# How is it better to do CRUD, with MongoDB or mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, model, crud

I have been trying to make sense of the whole Node.js, MongoDB and Mongoose, basically the MERN stack.
After several tutorials I still remain unclear about the CRUD operations methods. Sometimes I see them done in this format:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    Book.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        res.json(post);
    });
});
```

and other times I see them done in this format:

```
db.collection()
```

followed by a verb like `insert` or `findOne` or `insertOne` and some function.

I don't understand when I should use one or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mongodb native driver, which only provides connection to database, or Mongoose, which is ORM on top of mongod native driver. ORM means that you can specify schema, use various helpers and hooks. With native driver you cannot do that, you just have mongo as it is.

For starters better play with native driver and terminal mongo client, to get hang on how everything works. Later on you can read docs of mongoose and setup it, as Schema can be useful - you can see each collection document structure, on insert operation you make sure that only specified fields will be inserted. Though mongoose also coming with caveats, as any framework or library.